# hangindent + wrapfig = bad spacing?

Tags: spacing, indentation, wrapfigure

I am using the `wrapfig` package in order to place some text on the right side of my paragraph:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
        \fbox{Test}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

But when I set `\hangindent` to some positive length, the text/figure moves to the end of the paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
        \fbox{Test}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \setlength{\hangindent}{1cm}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wrapfig` uses `\parshape` to set the paragraph wrapping the figure. This is incompatible with setting `\hangindent` and indeed you get a warning

```
Package wrapfig Warning: Stationary wrapfigure forced to float on input line 9
```

because `wrapfig` checks whether the paragraph is set with a non zero `\hangindent` (or a non zero `\parshape`). There's *no* fix with `wrapfig` nor with `cutwin` and the only way, I believe, is to write your own `\parshape` specification.

Comment: Is there any alternative to `wrapfig` that would play nicely with `\hangindent`, or any alternative to `hangindent` that would play nicely with `wrapfig`?

Comment: @jtbandes Not that I know; basically you have to rewrite the `wrapfig` macros to take care of your `\hangindent` in the `\parshape` specification it creates. Not something I personally would try. :)